# I have a question about httpConnection and getResponseCode on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, httpconnection, getresponse

if I try to connect jpeg Camera, this connection works right. But When I connect to a Mjpeg (jpeg-stream) Camera, I can't show     "System.out.println("onreturn oncesi"
         + httpConnection.getResponseCode());"     on Output Console.
 I am using Emulator and MDS. I can show on MDS,    ... stream is coming.

```
url = getUrl();
queryString = encodeURL(queryString);    
byte postmsg[] = queryString.getBytes("UTF-8");
httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url
+ ";deviceside=false", Connector.READ_WRITE);
httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", getBase64Encode());
os = httpConnection.openDataOutputStream(); 

for (int i = 0; i < postmsg.length; i++) {
os.write(postmsg[i]);
}
{
 if (!cancel) {
     System.out.println(httpConnection.getURL()+ 
         " *****"+httpConnection.getPort());
     System.out.println("onreturn oncesi"
         + httpConnection.getResponseCode());
     onReturn(httpConnection.getResponseCode(), httpConnection
         .openInputStream(),(int) httpConnection.getLength());

     System.out.println("onreturn sornrası");
 }
 os.close();
 httpConnection.close();
}
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("hata " + e.getMessage());
try {
    httpConnection.close();
    Thread.sleep(60);
} catch (Exception ie) {
}
onError(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is your not setting your request headers correctly.

Your Posting data, so shouldn't `httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);` be `httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);`.

And you should also set the **content-Length**: `httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postmsg.length));`

And while we are at it I would go ahead and set these:

**content type**: maybe as "image/jpeg". Not sure what it should be for mJpeg...  `httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");`

**UserAgent** I have found that some sites block the default user-agent in RIM (Java/xxx), thinking it's a spider, so I like to set the user agent.`httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MyCoolApp/V1 (App_RIM)");`

What version of the JDE are you using?  Is this over HTTPS?  I ask because on older versions like 4.5 you had to create http and https differently.  In the newer versions you should probably use the new ConnectionFactory, instead of Connector.

Good Luck and I hope you figure it out!!!

Comment: I am using 4.6... ConnectionFactory doesnt work in 4.6, and I can't take responce code ...

Comment: @atasoyh if your opening an HTTPS connection make sure you cast the result from Connector to the correct Connection class.  I assume since your using Authorization, your connection is over HTTPS?  If so, cast to (HttpsConnection) not (HttpConnection).   Also search the Google for "Marcus Watkins and ConnectionFactory" (which works for 4.6), its not prefect but it will lead you in the right direction.